# ajax call to aws api gateway via hosted domain name does not work

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I use api gateway connected to lambda as a service.
When I create api gateway I am able to call it via following:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST','https:/apigateway url');
 xhr.onreadystatechange=function(event){

 console.log(event.target.response);
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
 "storyId": "100634850"
   }));
```

Now I created a custom domain name and attached it route 53. So I use a certificate as well as follows:

[image]

Now when I use the above code this time with a custom friendly name with certificate Ido not get anything back> Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you set up a Base Path Mapping?

Comment: Yeah I did and I pointed it to the stg and service I want. Is it not because of certificate?

Comment: The certificate needs to be valid for that domain name, i.e. the exact address, or uses a wildcard before the domain.

Comment: I mean, if you want to use the domain `email.alert.stg1.mydomain.com`, then you need to have a certificate that includes the full name or `*.alert.stg1.mydomain.com`. Alternatively change the API Gateway domain to `email-alert-stg1.mydomain.com` if you have a cert for `*.mydomain.com` that you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

- The API Resources have been deployed to a stage
- A Base Path Mapping has been added, e.g. www > [Select API] > [Select Stage]
- CORS is set up correctly for the client if in a browser
- The Certificate is for the right domain / wildcard, i.e. *.mydomainname.com
- A CNAME has been added in Route53 for the custom domain name to the "Target Domain Name"
- Your app has been updated to point to the new domain name + Base Path Mapping prefix

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested all the above and I have everything set as you mentioned. I use codepen to call. I mean my ajax call is from codepen which is not from the same certificate. Is it because of that ?

Comment: Probably not, I think it's most likely the custom domain name in API Gateway, does not match the certificate name. If you want to use the domain `email.alert.stg1.mydomainname.com`, then you need to have a certificate that includes the full name or `*.alert.stg1.mydomainname.com` as a primary or alternative domain name. Alternatively change the API Gateway domain to `email-alert-stg1.mydomainname.com` if you have a cert for `*.mydomainname.com` that you want to use